# how to delete a line that contains a word in all text files of a folder?

Tags: linux, bash

So, in linux, I have a folder with lots of big text files.

I want to delete all the lines of these files that contain a specific keyword. 
Is there any easy way to do that across all files?

Comment: He was tried trolling SO rep farmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There already many similar answers. I'd like to add that if you want to match `this is a line containing a keyword` but not `this is a line containing someoneelseskeyword`, then you had better added brackets around the word:

```
sed -i '/\<keyword\>/d' *.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I cannot test this right now, but it should get you started

```sh
find /path/to/folder -type f -exec sed -i '/foo/d' {} ';'
```

- find files in the directory `/path/to/folder`
- find lines in these files containing `foo`
- delete those lines from those files

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
for x in files*
do
    grep -v your_pattern "$x" > x && mv x "$x"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

sed -i '/keyword/d' *.txt -- run this in your directory.

sed - stream editor , use it here for deleting lines in individual files

-i option : to make the changes permenent in the input files

'/keywprd/' : specifies the pattern or the key to be searched in the files

option d : informs sed that matching lines need to be deleted.

*.txt : simply tells sed to use all the text files in the directory as input for
processing , you can specify a individual or a extension like *.txt the way i did.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
find your_path_filename |xargs sed -i '/key_word/d'
```

Comment: if you have filenames with spaces, you will need `-print0` option when using `find`, and `-0` in `xargs`. `find your_path_filename -print0 |xargs -0 sed -i '/key_word/d'`